# in R: Integrate in a function the posibility to see variables inside a dataframe with "tab"

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

As many know, when using a dplyr function in R studio, one could press "tab" to see the list of the available variables in a dataframe:

[image]

The question: How could I integrate this functionality inside a function I'm building?

Comment: This is not specific to functions from `dplyr`. This works with all functions. I just tried with `foo <- function(x) { print(x)}` and `iris |> foo()`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fZ8T.png

Comment: @stefan why doesnt this work for `janitor::tabyl(mtcars, TAB-HERE)`? It doesn't, for example see `gear`, (`janitor::tabyl(mtcars, gear)`). thanks

Comment: I just did some checks. And the "Tab"-Trick seems to work only when the package has been loaded via `library` and of course it only works when you use the pipe, whether `%>%` or `|>`.

Comment: so for brevity, this is the way to run my example to view variables `mtcars %>% tabyl(TAB-HERE)`